# DNN Search very slow

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 5.0. I have created a module in which I am providing some search criteria and a asp.net button. On click of button I am using greybox and displaying the search result on next page. on result page when I'm searching within database it takes around 30-35 seconds to retrieve the result. but on next call it takes 3-4 seconds.

I am unable to locate why it is slow for first time.

And it happens again if I leave the application for some time or again log in after 40-45 min, it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking at your database to see if the log files are large, perhaps the SearchItems, SearchItemWord, and Location tables are large?

Also check your event viewer (event log) to see if you have any errors being thrown when the first search occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try following link: [How I Get My DotNetNuke Sites To Run So Fast](http://www.mitchelsellers.com/blogs/articletype/articleview/articleid/283/how-i-get-my-dotnetnuke-sites-to-run-so-fast.aspx).